# Unable to clone repository using Egit and Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, git-clone, egit, git-cvs

I have windows server 2003 as my Operating Systme.

I am using WAMP for my php development.

I am using Eclipse Helios for PHP Developers for my development.

I have installed msysgit and tortoiseGit which comes for windows to manage repositories.

I have installed egit plugin in eclipse to manage project with team members.

I have referred following tutorial for EGIT that I found using google

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html.

Now I have following problem.

I have create one php project with name 'gittest'

I created repository by right clicking on project -> team -> share -> git

Now when I tried to create its clone using git protocol, with following settings

URI: git://Myserver/websites/gittest/.git
Host: Myserver
Repository Path: /websites/gittest/.git

it gives following error

**Cannot list available branches

Reason:
git://Myserver/websites/gittest/.git: Connection refused: connect**

same problem occurs with other protocols like http,ssh,ftp etc.

Can anyone help me about how to set this protocols so that I can share project with other team members on local network

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I was able to create server using method given on following link

https://github.com/LogosBible/GitOnCygwin/wiki

I used gitolite to create server as it is an advanced way to create git server and enhanced in many ways.

Following are some more links which might help anyone comming here in search of how to setup git server on your local pc or lan

http://therightstuff.de/CommentView,guid,b969ea4d-8d2c-42af-9806-de3631f4df68.aspx

http://jerabi.com/sdionne/blog/2010/09/06/git-repository-server-gitosis-on-win7-working/

http://java2cs2.blogspot.com/2010/03/setup-git-server-on-windows-machine.html

http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/

http://www.shannoncornish.com/blog/2009/04/git-server-windows-2008/

http://markembling.info/2009/08/git-server-gitosis-and-cygwin-on-windows

http://help.beanstalkapp.com/kb/git/setting-up-egit-in-eclipse-to-work-with-your-beanstalk-account

Hope this will help some one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The git protocol requires a git server running on Myserver.  The other protocols require server programs running too.  You do not have that.

You *can* have an area on the local network which you set up as a git repository which everybody use with the file protocol, but this will then be available to all using that shared drive as this method does not use any protection mechanism.

You may need system administration knowledge to do this properly.  I would suggest you bring this up with your local system administrator for best results.

Comment: Hello Andersen, Thanks for reply. I did not get you exactly. What do I need to install to setup git server? also I have shared folder of my project with team members on network. Regarding system administrator, I am the only person to do it. So if you can give me some more details, I can try that. Between I have got this link(http://www.shannoncornish.com/blog/2009/04/git-server-windows-2008/). do you want me to do something like that? Can't msysGit work as server?

Comment: msysgit is a port of the raw git command to Windows - it is not any of the servers you need.  If I were in your situation I would strongly consider signing up with github and let them do the system administration for you - https://github.com/plans - as you are too inexperienced right now and may accidentially loose data.